# AWS S3 storage access in Php script?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

This is a total newbie question, but I am wondering if there is an easy way to replace the following code:

A CODE - - - - - - - - - - -

```
foreach(glob('../music/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $playlist) {
   code here 
}
```

with "something" like this:

B CODE - - - - - - - - - - -

```
foreach(glob('http://mystorage.s3-website-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/music/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $playlist) {
   code here 
}
```

Code snippet "A" above works fine and the music directory is housed on the local server. Since the music directory houses lots of audio files (GBs), I am hoping I can somehow store all the audio files in an AWS S3 storage container and call them from AWS instead of storing them all on the local server. Code snippet "B" doesn't work of course. This illustrates what I am conceptually desiring to do. Can someone point me to an article that addresses this of offer any suggestions/solutions?

Comment: Saw this in another post - but still a bit cloudy? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/S3_QSAuth.html